# jQuery File Type Validation Based on Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, validation, file-type

I'm trying to validate file type base on radio button selection. If the user click on "Display Ad". He/She can only upload image files and if the user selects "Video", he/she can only upload video files. Furthermore, they can only upload file on certain size only which I might be able to do it later. The main problem for me now is I can't validate image file and video file. Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MZu3g/

Below is my sample code for the javascript.

```
$('.form_validation_reg3').validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    errorClass: 'error',
    validClass: 'valid',
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('div').addClass("f_error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('div').removeClass("f_error");
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element).closest('div').append(error);
    },
    rules: {
        'gender[]': {
            required: '#adtarget_check:checked',
            minlength: 1
        },
            'target_age[]': {
            required: '#adtarget_check:checked',
            minlength: 1
        },
            'target_time[]': {
            required: '#adtarget_check:checked',
            minlength: 1
        },
            'target_device[]': {
            required: '#adtarget_check:checked',
            minlength: 1
        },
            'target_location[]': {
            required: '#adtarget_check:checked',
            minlength: 1
        },
            'target_network[]': {
            required: '#adtarget_check:checked',
            minlength: 1
        },
        notebook: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1,
            accept: "jpg|jpeg|png|ico|bmp"
        },
        mobile: {
            required: false,
            minlength: 1,
            accept: "jpg|jpeg|png|ico|bmp"
        },
    },
    invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
        $.sticky("There are some errors or no Ads image were selected. Please correct them and submit again.", {
            autoclose: 8000,
            position: "top-right",
            type: "st-error"
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution... by adding these..

```
var radio_value = null;
$("input[name='tabnote_radio']").change(function() {
    radio_value = this.value;
    if ( radio_value == "image") {
        $('#notebook').rules('add', {
            extension: "jpg|jpeg|png|gif"
        });
    } else if( radio_value == "video") {
        $('#notebook').rules('add', {
            extension: "flv|mov|mp4|wmv|ogv"
        });
    };
});
```

This can be useful too: http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/490-how-to-add-and-remove-validation-rules-jquery-validate-plugin-

Comment: for image, you can add filesize:1048576... But for video file, it give me error... I'm lookin for answers too...

Answer (score 1):

Since your fiddle did not include the jquery.validate.js script, I'm not sure if that was the problem, or if the problem is that you forgot to include the [additional-methods.js](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js), which is where the `accept` rule lives.  If you don't have that, your `accept` rule will never work, and will throw errors (which you should have included in your question!).

So to be clear, this is what your scripts should look like:

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>    
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/MZu3g/1/

Comment: The accept rule works, I have those jquery included.. The only problem I have now is to have separate rule. When user chooses video, he/she only able to upload video files and vice versa if choose "display ad" only able to upload image files.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128657/jquery-validation-changing-rules-dynamically/4129124#4129124).  What you want to do is use the `change` function of the radio button to swap out all the rules for the upload field.

Comment: Ryley, I came across this also, and seems a bit complicated to me. But anyway, I found another solution to my problem.

Comment: Sure. Your solution is fundamentally the same as what I proposed, but good enough, glad you figured it out!