# how can i control jquery validation engine control with multiple buttons?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Validation - Multiple submit buttons on one asp.net form, different validation groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602911/jquery-validation-multiple-submit-buttons-on-one-asp-net-form-different-valid)

I am using jQuery validation engine plugin and I have two buttons in my content page: one of them is a submit buttton, and the other one is a cancel button.

When I click on the submit button, the form validation fires but when I click on the cancel button, the form validation fires again. I don't want to fire validation when the cancel button is clicked.

Any idea ?

```
<form>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="validate[required]" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="validate[required]" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="send" />
</form>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="cancel" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an asp.net question.

You can just add `CausesValidation="False"` as an attribute:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="cancel" CausesValidation="False" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Mention the type of the button. Button with no type inside a form will be considered as submit button.

Just specify the type as button for cancel button. This will not trigger validation